# Why does my list inclusion negation not work?

Tags: python-3.x

As part of a (Python 3.3) program I am writing, I am comparing two lists; I want to find every member of the second list that does not occur in the first list so that I can build a database command.  The "in" membership test works as I expect, but its negation does not.

For instance:

```
l1 = ['MNE11B', 'DLC05A', 'MKH08A', 'PERGDM', 'DLW12B', 'FSW08A', 'PNC12A', 'KHH04A', 'BWD12A', 'YDB12A']
l2 = ['MKH08A', 'FSW08A', 'BWD12A']

print("Present")
for x in l2:
    if x in l1:
        print(x)

print("Not present")
for x in l2:
    if x not in l1:
        print(x)
```

The first "for" loop prints out the three members in l2 that also exist in l1.  I would expect the second loop to print out the members in l2 that are not in l1; it instead prints nothing at all.  Why is this?  I have tried various syntactical tricks with parentheses and such, but this is being stubborn.

Comment: Because `all(x in l1 for x in l2)`.  Because `set(l2) - set(l1)` is the empty set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Every* item in `l2` is in `l1`, so `if x not in l1` will always evaluate to `False`.

```
>>> l1 = ['MNE11B', 'DLC05A', 'MKH08A', 'PERGDM', 'DLW12B', 'FSW08A', 'PNC12A', 'KHH04A', 'BWD12A', 'YDB12A']
>>> l2 = ['MKH08A', 'FSW08A', 'BWD12A']
>>> for x in l2:
    if x not in l1:
        print(x)


>>> l2.append('XYZ31T')
>>> for x in l2:
    if x not in l1:
        print(x)

XYZ31T
```

Comment: Doh!  That's what I get for doing too many things at one time.  I looked at this on and off for maybe an hour and it never occurred to me that I was doing it backwards.  Thanks!